How to detect Esc key using Unix module and raw mode?
This is the code in OCaml to detect keys using the Unix module and raw mode in the linux terminal.
The only key I can't detect is ESC. There could be others, but my main goal is to detect ESC key.
Here is the code of the function:
    (* Function to read a character and recognize special keys *)
    let read_character () =
      let in_chan = in_channel_of_descr stdin in
      let c = input_char in_chan in
      if c = '\027' then
        let next1 = input_char in_chan in
        let next2 = input_char in_chan in
        match (next1, next2) with
        | ('[', 'A') -> "Up Arrow"
        | ('[', 'B') -> "Down Arrow"
        | ('[', 'C') -> "Right Arrow"
        | ('[', 'D') -> "Left Arrow"
        | ('[', 'H') -> "Home"
        | ('[', 'F') -> "End"
        | ('[', '3') when input_char in_chan = '~' -> "Delete"
        | ('[', '2') when input_char in_chan = '~' -> "Insert"
        | ('[', '5') when input_char in_chan = '~' -> "Page Up"
        | ('[', '6') when input_char in_chan = '~' -> "Page Down"
        | _ -> "Ignore"
      else
        match c with
        | '\n' -> "Enter"        (* Handle Enter key *)
        | '\127' -> "Backspace"  (* Handle Backspace (DEL) *)
        | _ -> String.make 1 c   (* Return single character *)


Please, take into account that C/curses works, but it is very slow to initialize/finish and it clears the screen, so it is not an optimal option.
It is kind of a challenge. AI suggested me using Lwt/Async, but none of that worked, since I didn't have success installing that in Arch Linux.

When you're in canonical mode, the terminal driver doesn't return any input to the application until you press Enter. So you can't process escape sequences immediately.

It would be very helpful to know why you want to do this, as there's likely an XY problem and a better solution at the bottom of this.

Possible dupe: How to read one character at a time from user input — at each keystroke (without waiting for the user to press the return key)?

Fortunately there is a non-canonical mode with timeout which allows this. The complete source code is this:
open Unix

(* Function to set the terminal to raw mode with no echo and a short timeout *)
let set_raw_mode () =
  let term = tcgetattr stdin in
  let raw_term = { term with c_icanon = false; c_echo = false } in
  raw_term.c_vmin <- 1;
  raw_term.c_vtime <- 1;  (* Timeout of 0.1 seconds *)
  tcsetattr stdin TCSANOW raw_term

(* Function to restore the original terminal settings *)
let restore_terminal old_term =
  tcsetattr stdin TCSANOW old_term

(* Function to read keys and recognize special keys *)
let read_keys () =
  let buffer = Bytes.create 6 in
  let len = Unix.read Unix.stdin buffer 0 6 in
  let raw_input = Bytes.sub_string buffer 0 len in
  match raw_input with
  | "\027[A" -> "Up Arrow"
  | "\027[B" -> "Down Arrow"
  | "\027[C" -> "Right Arrow"
  | "\027[D" -> "Left Arrow"
  | "\027[H" -> "Home"
  | "\027[F" -> "End"
  | "\027[3~" -> "Delete"
  | "\027[2~" -> "Insert"
  | "\027[5~" -> "Page Up"
  | "\027[6~" -> "Page Down"
  | "\027" -> "Esc"
  | _ ->
    if len = 1 && Bytes.get buffer 0 = '\n' then "Enter"
    else if len = 1 && Bytes.get buffer 0 = '\127' then "Backspace"
    else raw_input

let () =
  let old_term = tcgetattr stdin in
  try
    set_raw_mode ();
    let rec loop () =
      let key = read_keys () in
      print_endline ("Key pressed: " ^ key);
      if key <> "Esc" then loop ()
    in
    loop ();
    restore_terminal old_term
  with e ->
    restore_terminal old_term;
    raise e


The Esc key generates the single ESC byte (octal 027), whereas other special keys generate an escape sequence beginning with this byte.
Therefore, there is no fully reliable way of detecting the Esc keypress in terminals.
One possibility, done probably most notably by the vi family, is to check for the ESC byte without any other byte immediately available. This works pretty well in practice, although strictly speaking there could be cases when depending on the timing of events can go wrong. A variation to this is to allow for a bit of additional delay while waiting for followup bytes.
Another possibility, also often seen in terminal based applications, is to expect the user to press the Esc key twice. This is straightforward to detect without heuristics, but results in a less pleasant user experience.
